# C# Mono+Winforms MessageBox problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

I have a file called **hellowf.cs**

```
class MyFirstApp {
static void Main() {
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello, Mono+WinForms!");
   }
}
```

On Ubuntu 8.10, I do the following

```
gmcs hellowf.cs -r:System.Drawing.dll -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll
mono hellowf.exe
```

... and it looks like this:

[alt text http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/4674/helloproblemuk5.png](http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/4674/helloproblemuk5.png)

---

The second part of the message is missing. Why is this happening? The same binary - **hellowf.exe** - works fine on Windows.

---

Update: 
This is really annoying. Here are the mono versions I have had and tried to make this work on so far:

```
    1.9.1 (from official ubuntu repo)
    2.0.1 (from some some 3rd party repo)
    2.2   (wiped every mono pkg and compiled myself)
```

My Current mono version:

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.2 (tarball Wed Jan 14 22:58:21 CET 2009)
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
gmcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 2.2.0.0
```

... any clues?

Comment: What version of libmono-windorms you have installed?

Comment: Previously I had the 2.0 version. I have wiped out all of mono and installed everything from the current 2.2 source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found a workaround. This seems to be a bug in Mono related to font rendering. It happens when "**Full**" hinting is turned on. I usually have it that way. Changing it to "**Slight**" or "**Medium**" in `System->Preferences->Appearance->Fonts->Details` fixes the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: At a guess, Mono was calculating the size of the box before hinting, then after hinting it needed to word-wrap the message to fit it into the width...

Answer (score 1):

Works OK on opensuse 11.0, mono 2.0.1.

Please, edit your question and put the mono version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

stick an @ in front of the "Hello, Mono+WinForms!" and see if it still happens.

Comment: Unfortunately it still happens after prefixing the string literal.

Comment: bummer, not sure then, this sounds weird.

Comment: maybe words with WinForms don't run on mono :P

Answer (score 0):

Standard debugging advice:
Start making small, controlled changes, and see what happens.
This will help narrow down what the problem is.

Try removing the symbols: , + !
Try removing the space.
Try a variety of shorter strings, and possibly some longer strings.

Once you have a better idea of what the MessageBox will and will not print, you can start to debug that specific problem, instead of trying to debug, "It doesn't work!"

Comment: I have already done a lot of small changes and updated Mono from 1.9.1 to 2.0.1 and then compiled 2.2 from source. It cuts everything from the first space in the string.

Comment: Furthermore this is clearly a bug in the implementation, so don't act like the hello world code copied from a book is wrong.

Comment: @gdivos: I think you have answered your question: It is a bug in the implementation. I have not "acted like the hello world code copied from a book is wrong". Getting snippy will get you no help. Goodbye.

Comment: @abelenky, judging from the timestamps it looks like he got snippy after he already figured out the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

When you updated your packages and source code, did you update/compile libgdiplus?  We have seen some funky graphical problems if the System.Drawing and libgdiplus versions get out of sync.

Comment: Yes, first I compiled and "make install"-ed libgdiplus and then mono.

Comment: Jonathan, if it's not too much trouble could you please look at my GTK# question? Miguel was there but I don't know if he'll be back :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219918/ Thanks in advance...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know anything about Gtk# or OSX.  I try to answer the questions I can, but that one is outside my frame of reference.  Sorry man.  Best of luck!