# Newbie Question: GTK# (Mono) on OSX

Tags: macos, mono, gtk#

I am taking my [first steps](http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/gtksharptutorial/firststeps/) (or perhaps my last steps) in GTK# on Mono for OSX. I write a .cs file and then try to compile with mono:

```
gmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 one.cs
```

this results in this message

```
error CS8027: Couldn't run pkg-config: ApplicationName='pkg-config', CommandLine='--libs gtk-sharp-2.0', CurrentDirectory=''
```

Which would, apparently, require me to know what I'm doing. I do know that

> Mono's Installer for MacOS X comes
>   with Gtk+ and Gtk# so you can start
>   building and running cross-platform
>   GUI Gtk# applications that include
>   OSX."

So there's nothing to install.

<strike>I do find GTK2 here</strike>

```
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/x11/gtk2/
```

which was definitely installed by the Mono installation.

Gmcs version is 2.4.2.2.

**Edit:** Miguel says I have something weird in my path.

I have removed all Macports following Macports instructions. I have reinstalled Mono from the .dmg. Here is my current path

```
export PATH=/opt/subversion:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

but even if use just /usr/bin it's still not avoiding the error.

ALL Mono stuff is where it's supposed to be, including all the stuff in `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current`. **HOWEVER:** strangely

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.4.2.2/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0/
```

is empty. But MonoDevelop runs, but doesn't know about Gtk (I've included all the references it knows about)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/pkg-config ./pkg-config
```

Now your gmcs -pkg:... command will work.

Background: I hit this exact problem on a new Mac and a fresh install of Mono. Left me scratching my head for a few days until I took a close look at the error message:

```
error CS8027: Couldn't run pkg-config: ApplicationName='pkg-config', CommandLine='--libs gtk-sharp-2.0', CurrentDirectory=''
```

It's saying it couldn't run the program, so I did a

```
which pkg-config
```

That came up blank, so I thought probably it couldn't run it because it wasn't in the path. And that turned out to be it.

Comment: Thanks Yawar. I'll mark this as best answer for now, and in the next month (it's December 2009) I'll give this a shot and see if it works for me. Problem is I haven't touched this stuff in a few months (been using pure Winforms). Sure looks right.

Comment: Another (better?) option is to just add the mono bin directory to your path.   `export PATH=${PATH}:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin`

Comment: @Cheeso - sure, that should work fine. Matter of preference, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mixed setup.

The Gtk in /opt/local/var/macports did not come from Mono's installer for OSX, you probably got it earlier from macports.   The Mono installer places its files under /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/

Chances are, you have something else on your path, since it works out of the box after I installed the Mono.Framework from the Mono web site (with the command line example that you have above).

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I'll report back if I resolve this or have other questions. (+1 para vos, por supuesto)

Comment: Sorry, do you mean "path" as in echo $PATH or... what environment vars should I be looking at?

Comment: Miguel, I've edited the question again after your comments, if you get a chance to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Using MonoDevelop might make things easier, but here is how it references gtk# while compiling (note that it references the assembly straight from the GAC):

gmcs test.cs -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll

You'll usually also need to include references to gdk-sharp and pango-sharp and glib-sharp, btw.

Note in the path that the framework version is "Current", which makes the command a little more future-proof.

Comment: Thanks for that, Sandy, and good luck here on SO. I'll be checking that out shortly, although it seems like my favorite Mono strategy -- waiting -- is a good one as the whole thing advances.